# nginx's ngx_http_limit_conn_module don't work for https

Tags: nginx

I use nginx's(nginx1.10.2) ngx_http_limit_conn_module module to limit the number of concurrent connections. It works for HTTP requests, but it doesn't work for HTTPS.nginx config as follows

```
limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=one:10m;
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  test-esign.mbcloud.com;
    #ssl on;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/conf.d/crtdomain/server.cer";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/conf.d/crtdomain/server.key";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        limit_conn one 1;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you try and split your server blocks and see if there is a different outcome? Try using a server block for http and one for https. It would be a good idea, also, to decide on which protocol you want to use and perform a redirect from one to the other - but i guess its really up to you...

Comment: [ask] Thanks for your idea,but it still doesn't work.nginx config as follows                                                                                     
limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=one:10m;
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    .......
    location / {
        limit_conn one 1;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
server {
    listen    80;
    .....
    location / {
        limit_conn one 1;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}

Comment: I use ab command test it.  In http(ab -n 10 -c 5 http://.../index.html)  request,it works,the nginx errorlog reponse 503.In the https(ab -n 10 -c 5 https://.../index.html) request,reponse 200 at all

Comment: Try updating your nginx version and see if it helps